# Bootstrap / CSS fixed header got big jump

Tags: css, header

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/muchproblem/w5db40wx/

I am a newbie to web development, and I come up with a (maybe silly) question, how to fix a div when scroll down.

I got two div, 
1) mainheader, that i want to fix below the bootstrap header when scroll down
2) namecard, that I want to 'hide' when scroll down.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 80) {
    $('.mainheader').addClass('fixed')
  } else {
    $(".mainheader").removeClass('fixed');
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 80) {
    $('.namecard').hide
  } else {
    $(".namecard").show);
}
});
```

But after testing with my code, when scrolling down, it got a 'big jump' when the 'mainheader' is fixed and 'namecard' got hidden, so that some of the rows in content could never be read and hidden after the 'fixed mainheader'....anyone can offer some help on this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: why are you *fixing* it `onScroll` simply set its `position: fixed` by default and if you want to do something `onScroll` then write for that class you're adding `onScroll` the it wont jump surely

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick play with your code and placed them inside at the bottom of the `<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">` this basically adds them to your navbar and fixes it just below.

In answer to the second part of your questions I'm not sure. Hope I helped a bit.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="" src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid mainheader">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
          <p>Mainheader</p>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <form class="inline" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search" id="Search">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid namecard">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <p>Namecard</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    

    A
    <br>B
    <br>C
    <br>D
    <br>E
    <br>F
    <br>G
    <br>H
    <br>I
    <br>J
    <br>K
    <br>L
    <br>M
    <br>N
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: add margin-top for ".mainheader". the value of margin top will be equal or greater than height of the fixed header height.